# "lsof -i" Command output explanation

Tags: terminal, command-line

i am attempting to maintain a closer eye on my Apple-Mac's outgoing and incoming connections; in collaboration with other processes such as `tcpdump` and `netstat`, i have been using the command: `lsof -i`, which allegedly displays all processes using the internet.

The output of this command is fairly simple, however does return some confusing results, including multiple instances of the process `com.apple` which has little to no explanation online. Whilst listing Spotify and its various related processes such as `SpotifyWE`, the command declines to list other applications which i happen to know are using the network, such as Safari and Mail.

To simplify things, my questions are:

- What is the purpose of the process `com.apple`?
- Why are there multiple listings of the same process?
- Why are some processes/applications which are definitely using the internet omitted from the command (`lsof -i`)`s result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lsof's output is truncated. Paste the following command into Terminal:

```
ps -Ac|grep com.apple
```

This'll show you all the processes it could be referring to. You'll have to look at their PID to know which is which (second column in lsof, first column in ps).

A process will only be listed if it is has an active connection to somewhere. Not all applications maintain an active connection at all times.

Comment: ahh ok, so they are not multiple instances of the same process, instead multiple separate processes, we just can't see the full process name. And i have verified your theory about the command only listing active connections at that time by launching Mail, the theory seems to be correct

Comment: Hypothetically, if i had a key logger which was transmitting my keystrokes off-site, the process would be listed in this commands output wouldn't it? Assuming it wasn't somehow masked.

Comment: It would be, yes. There are ways to piggyback on other connections for the more elite hackers though, but it isn't common. :)

Comment: Yeah that does make sense, interesting, thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure! :)